# Use both alpha and stat_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to apply alpha to a smoothed line in the most recent version of ggplot2. I have a plot that was broken in the December update. Toy example of that plot:

```
dat <- mtcars
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
plotdat <- dat %>% group_by(hp) %>% summarise(ave = mean(wt))
ggplot(plotdat, aes(hp,ave)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, alpha = .2) +
  geom_line(size = 2, alpha = .2, stat = "smooth")
#Warning message:
#Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
#object 'auto' of mode 'function' was not found
```

The above code worked in past versions, but now throws a warning. Of course using the geom_smooth approach does not allow you to access alpha for the smoothed line, because the alpha command controls the ribbon.

```
ggplot(plotdat, aes(hp,ave)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, alpha = .1) +
  geom_smooth(size = 2, se = FALSE, alpha = .1)
```

Produces a plot close to what I want. How can I produce the dark blue smoothed line with alpha / transparency?

(Note that the second alpha is not taking effect.)

[image]

Comment: Using stat_smooth() directly is providing the result with packageVersion('ggplot2')
[1] ‘2.0.0’

Comment: Please add the figure you used to get, so everybody would be able to see what you are talking about.

Comment: @user3949008 - does that provide the needed alpha functionality?

Comment: So the question is, how do we get an alpha on the smooth line I guess...

Comment: @MikeWise It did plot the smoothed line with confidence interval around it all the way. So, it is working on my end.

Comment: Yes, but it is about the alpha... Or so I understood the question. I think this is yet another ggplot2 2.0.0 regression. There are a few...

Comment: I think the first warning is telling you that you might need define the method to use for the smoothed line. Like `method = "loess"` or whatever other method you want to use.

Comment: Hi @MikeWise, you're understanding correctly and thanks for the edits. I clarified a final question which hopefully helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @aosmith for the suggestion. I was able to get a working answer by directly specifying the method as "loess" in geom_line.

```
dat <- mtcars
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
plotdat <- dat %>% group_by(hp) %>% summarise(ave = mean(wt))
ggplot(plotdat, aes(hp,ave)) +
  geom_line(size = 2, alpha = .2) +
  geom_line(size = 2, alpha = .2, stat = "smooth", method = "loess")
```